# Flatmaping a n-order tree structure : Java Streams

Tags: java, tree, java-stream, flatten

Suppose I have a non-binary tree structure (each node may have `n` child nodes). In that sense, what could be a good method for flattening the whole tree into a single list using java **streams**?

```
rootNode.getChildren().stream()
    .flatMap(node -> node.getChildren().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This example is what I would do for a single level flattening, and still such would not include the root node (which is desired).

Comment: @Ricola That doesn't use streams in any way. How is it a possible dupe?

Comment: The second most voted answer (mine actually) uses streams. Anyway I copied and adapted it as an answer here.

Comment: @Ricola having a specific title helps someone googling for this, like me a few moments ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets call your class `Node`. In that class, add the method (assuming `getChildren()` never return `null`) :

```
public Stream<Node> streamAll(){
    return Stream.concat(Stream.of(this), getChildren().stream().flatMap(Node::streamAll));
}
```

Then to get a list, you can simply call

```
rootNode.streamAll().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or since java 16

```
rootNode.streamAll().toList();
```